# SubForm 1 filters SubForm 2 on different Tabs

Tags: ms-access, tabs, vba, filtering

I am trying to link SubForm 1 in one tab to SubForm 2 in a different tab on the same form so that when I click a row in SubForm 1 on the first tab it filters SubForm 2 on the other tab:

I have tried the following SQL code inside SubForm 2:

```
SELECT Payment.WOrderID, Payment.PymtDate, Payment.PymtMethod, Payment.Amount, Payment.Rate, Payment.CheckNum, Payment.TransNum
FROM Payment
WHERE (((Payment.WOrderID)=[Forms]![Main Menu]![Main Menu SubForm].[Form]![txtWOrderID]));
```

Then in the OnClick Event of the tab for SubForm 2 I put this VBA:

```
Forms![Main Menu]![Main Menu SubForm 3].Refresh
```

I will filter the subform but I always get the top reference, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What i'm doing in this situation, i create a hidden textbox on the main form (lets Name it txtMainWOrderID).

on the Current event of SubForm 1 i set the value of txtMainWOrderID on the main form to the value of SubForm 1 txtWOrderID.

Now i link SubForm 2 to the txtMainWOrderID (in you case i figure, Link Master Fields:txtMainWOrderID, Link Child Fields:txtWOrderID) so it gets automatically updated when i click a row in subform 1 & you won't need the WHERE inside your SQL Statement.

hope i understood your question & i explained it enough.

Comment: How do I change the Link Master in SubForm 2 to the txtMainWOrderID... it says the value isn't in the list?

Comment: just type it in the properties, don't press the button on the right.

Comment: When I do that it filters a row with just the Work Order ID in SubForm 2, none of the other values in the sub-form are listed.

Comment: what is your SQL Statement for subform 2 ?

Comment: `SELECT 
FROM Payment;
`

Comment: you need to select a field from the table, write "SELECT * FROM Payment" etc.

Comment: It is still not doing it... it shows it as if it were a new record.